# How to split string based on another string

Tags: c#, split

I have a string:

```
string fileName = VAH007157100_REINSTMT_20d5fe49.tiff
```

I want to split this at the end of REINSTMT.

```
string splittedFileName = fileName.split("REINSTMT")[0];
```

The above does not work.

How would I go about splitting it to grab everything from the left side of the word "REINSTMT"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
string splittedFileName = fileName.Split(new string[]{"REINSTMT"},
                                                  StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to split based on a string rather than a char, you need to provide a second argument. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).

What you probably want is

```
string splittedFileName = fileName.split(new string[] {"REINSTMT"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be with substring:

```
string fileName = "VAH007157100_REINSTMT_20d5fe49.tiff";
string splittedFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("REINSTMT"));
```